# Unix: I want capture the output of top into variable instead of file

Tags: variables, unix, top-command

I want to capture the output of top into a variable instead of a file.

And I tried the below

```
top -n 1 -b | head > top_op
echo "inside: $top_op"
$top_op | grep Cpu > Cpu
echo "$Cpu"
```

But my output is just

```
Inside:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store output to variables, use command substitution:

```
top_op=$(top -n 1 -b | head)
echo "inside: $top_op"
Cpu=$(echo "$top_op" | grep Cpu)
echo "$Cpu"
```

Using backquotes is the but `$()` is more recommended as it could be recursive without quoting.

```
top_op=`top -n 1 -b | head`
```